# A command that generates both standard error and output

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I want to do some troubleshooting on my bash script. Is there a short and simple command that generates both `stdout` and `stderr` so that I can use `2>&1` on it? Sorry if this looks trivial, but I just can't think of one at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use `ls` to list actual and imaginary files:

```
ls . *.blah
```

This assumes that there *are* visible files in the working directory and that you *don't* have any files that end in `.blah`<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1. ...and if you do, we won't judge you.</sub>

Comment: That won't work in zsh, fish, csh, tcsh and `bash -O failglob`. (and `ls .` may return nothing on stdout if the current directory only has hidden files/dirs). Better `ls / /x`

Answer (score 7):

Just write a subshell which sends to `stdout` and `stderr`...

```
(echo STDOUT && echo STDERR >&2)
```

For proof that it works:

```
(echo STDOUT && echo STDERR >&2) > STDOUT.txt 2> STDERR.txt
```

This will create files `STDOUT.txt` and `STDERR.txt` containing the words `STDOUT` and `STDERR` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls / /x
df / /x
wc / /etc/passwd
od / /dev/null
```

To guaranteed stdout written *before* stderr:

```
(w;/) # Bourne/csh like shells only.
sh -c 'w;/'
'time' w
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to use later:

```
gen_stdout_stderr() {                                                           
    printf "%s\n" "STDERR" >&2                                                  
    printf "%s\n" "STDOUT"                                                      
}
```

Then:

```
$ gen_stdout_stderr 
STDERR
STDOUT
```